# How can I copy the DynamicData templates from another site?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2008, dynamic-data

I'm attempting to start using DynamicData functionality in a previously existing website.  Basically I'm following [this tutorial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668188.aspx).  When I got to the part about creating the Field Templates I decided I could probably create a new site with the Dynamic Data stuff built in, and then just copy the folder over.

Unfortunately when I do that and try to compile I get the error "Could not load type..." for just about every .ascx file in the DynamicData directory.  I named the "new" project the same as the pre-existing site so that the namespace would be the same... but I can't think of what else I could be missing.

Everything looks ok, except that the *.ascx.Designer.cs files are showing inside the Solution Explorer.  I tried deleting one and then copying that file back into just the directory but it didn't work.  I'm assuming I need to do something special with those so that Visual studio handles them properly and can compile?

Here is one of the .aspx files:

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" CodeBehind="FilterUserControl.ascx.cs" Inherits="EService.FilterUserControl" %>

<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" 
    EnableViewState="true" ontextchanged="new">
    <asp:ListItem Text="All" Value="" />
</asp:DropDownList>
```

Here is the matching .cs file:

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Specialized;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Security;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts;
using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.Web.DynamicData;

namespace EService
{
    public partial class FilterUserControl : System.Web.DynamicData.FilterUserControlBase
    {
        public event EventHandler SelectedIndexChanged
        {
            add
            {
                DropDownList1.SelectedIndexChanged += value;
            }
            remove
            {
                DropDownList1.SelectedIndexChanged -= value;
            }
        }

        public override string SelectedValue
        {
            get
            {
                return DropDownList1.SelectedValue;
            }
        }

        protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!Page.IsPostBack)
            {
                PopulateListControl(DropDownList1);

                // Set the initial value if there is one
                if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(InitialValue))
                    DropDownList1.SelectedValue = InitialValue;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And here is the .ascx.designer.cs file:

```
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// <auto-generated>
//     This code was generated by a tool.
//     Runtime Version:2.0.50727.1433
//
//     Changes to this file may cause incorrect behavior and will be lost if
//     the code is regenerated.
// </auto-generated>
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

namespace EService
{


    public partial class FilterUserControl
    {

        protected System.Web.UI.WebControls.DropDownList DropDownList1;
    }
}
```

EDIT:  If I create the file in the website, then copy the contents from the temporary site I created it seems to compile just fine.  Really have no idea what the issue is here... I tried manually modifying files to match the results of copying and they still wouldn't work unless I actually created them in the site.  It's just bizarre...

Answer (score 0):

The problem was due to the temporary site creating the <%@ Control > definitions with the CodeBehind property instead of the CodeFile property.  For some reason pages in the actual website will only compile when CodeFile is declared...

Answer (score 0):

DD will work with Either **Website** or **Web Application**. however when copying in from an other project the types need to be the same otherwise it's lot of editing to convert swee my article here [Getting Dynamic Data Futures filters working in a File Based Website.](http://csharpbits.notaclue.net/2008/09/dynamic-data-futures-advanced-filters.html)